# Authorization is required to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, blogger, google-docs, urlfetch

I have a script that converts a Google Doc to a Blogger post ( saving the images to Picasa along the way )... I have used the PicasaApp library.

I want to run the app as "User accessing the web app" so that people can use it on their docs and with their blogs.

It works fine for me, but always returns "Authorization is required to perform that action." when used with another google account.

I have a function that runs test code for talking to DocList, PicasaApp and Blogger via the API. They all force me, the author to authenticate and it works fine. I even tried changing the the name of googleOAuth_ to my_googleOAuth ( see below)  in case it was clashing with the googleOAuth_ in PicasaApp.

```
function my_googleOAuth(name,scope) {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous"); // Client ID:
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous"); //Client secret
    return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

This is really driving me nuts, and it seems there isn't a clear answer anywhere about what to do. I've done the edit/save/run loop a dozen different ways.

Comment: By the way, this blogger my_googleOAuth only works if I use my real setConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret .

Comment: Did you publish your script using "Deploy as web app" and chose the appropriate "Execute the app as"-option?

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately is known limitation with authorize the effective user against UrlFetch/OAuth1 and there is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1525) on issue tracker for it.

What you could do is manually do the OAuth 2 flow here and store the tokens yourselves in `UserProperties`. Here is some [example OAuth2 code](https://gist.github.com/entaq/4079885) and you'll need to create your OAuth2 client ID/secret at [developers.google.com/console](http://developers.google.com/console)

Comment: Thanks Arun... oAuth2 really looked like it was working, I got the "let's get started" link, the oAuth screen and then the dreaded ..."Authorization is required to perform that action."

Comment: Oh hang on. Dur! I've implemented your oAuth2 but the Picasa code is still accessing via oAuth1.

Comment: Given that I was attempting to make an app to teach people how to make a simple app, oAuth2 is a bit of an overblown brain ache isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me just now was the solution here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50960/27487

It is also mentioned in the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#common_errors

In short:

1. In the Script editor, run the a function manually from the dropdown menu
2. An authorization popup shows
3. Grant access
4. Re-run the app as normal, and you should not get the authorization error